# How to import stack component from Material-ui (the import on the website doesn't work)

Tags: material-ui

Hi i'm trying to use the stack component from material ui. I use a lot of material ui component and they all work just fine but for some reason using the import route from the offical material ui doc doesn't seem to work.

`import { Accordion, AccordionDetails, Stack, Grid, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';`

It simply says that: "Module '"@material-ui/core"' has no exported member 'Stack'."

It does the same exact thing if i try the other import route:
`import Stack from '@material-ui/core/Stack';`

I am really confused as to what is going on here. Anybody has any idea?

Comment: Which version of material-ui you are using? Can you install  next version and try again? `npm install @material-ui/core@next @emotion/react @emotion/styled`

Comment: Oh nice i actually tried doing npm install @material-ui/core with no result. I wasn't aware of the @next part. This seem to have resolved it thanks

Comment: Seems like the latest beta (1) removed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stack component is not available in V4. It is only available in V5.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, look to the [documentaion](https://mui.com/api/stack/)

> import { Stack } from '@mui/material';